# Unable to commit with fossil scm

Tags: version-control, fossil

Recently I could not commit due to the following error:

```
$ fossil commit
$EDITOR './ci-comment-CEA221250987.txt'
Unsafe command string: $EDITOR './ci-comment-CEA221250987.txt'
              here ----^
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is this a fossil issue or do I have some rogue configuration in my `.bashrc` ?

---

My fossil version is

```
$ fossil version
This is fossil version 2.12.1 [b98ce23d4f] 2020-08-20 13:27:04 UT
```

And `$EDITOR` is

```
$ echo $EDITOR
vim
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does "fossil setting editor" say?  Do you have it set to $EDITOR?  Don't
do that.  It is a security risk.  The error arises because Fossil detected that
security risk and refused to proceed.  Instead, set the editor directly to "vim"
like this:

```
fossil setting editor vim
```

Or, do "fossil unset editor" so that the VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables
will be consulted at runtime.

Note:  In the above, you might need to add the --global option to the various
"setting" and "unset" commands, in case you have "editor" set globally.